# Search engines and removed questions

Tags: discussion, link-rot

Before I ask a question on Stack Overflow, I try googling. When I google for "visibility of panel in vb.net," I got [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990499/panels-visible-property-changes-from-true-to-false-automatically) in Google. When I click on that link I got:

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

I know what it means. Why did the search engine show that link, if the question was already removed? Is there any mechanism to hide questions from search engines, when they are removed?

Comment: Probably because the search engine indexed it before it was removed? The question is 3 hours old and was removed half an hour ago before it got any answers - Google simply didn't manage to recrawl it yet.