# Are closed questions also crawled by search engines?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I gave an answer a few days back. The question I answered was later closed by moderators for being an "exact duplicate," among other reasons. However, the question's title was much more in line with the general language that users prefer to search with on search engines than the duplicate's title.

Are closed questions also crawled by Google/Yahoo? Can normal users find links to duplicate questions through search engines?

Comment: see also [Is a duplicate question considered a generally bad or good thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144608) and [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search engines and removed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135618/search-engines-and-removed-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As long as the question does not get deleted, it's still completely visible and can be indexed by search engines. The only difference is now there's a [closed] notice attached to the post. For a duplicate, this will allow visitors to find even more information about the topic in the other question(s).

Comment: I've Googled some really basic things while getting deeper into Javascript, and kind of chuckle at the great wall of `[closed]` that shows up in the results.

Comment: @TimPost: I even got a first link in search results but the question was deleted. So that means google showed me broken SO link as first result.